# Two Play Projects Depend on Common project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, devops

I have two separate Play Framework 2.6.x projects, both have their own routes.

Both of them want to share the same models, actions, and other code which essentially have no dependencies.

Everything is all under the same VCS root.

What is the best way to organize the project structure such that we can have both Play projects have access to / depend on the common models & actions, and follow-up, would we also be able to share the routes such that you can get compile time safety on accessing the other Play applications routes?

Edit: Here's where I'm currently at...
Structure looks like this

`parent
  common
     build.sbt
  other
     build.sbt
  build.sbt`

Parents build.sbt looks like the following:

```
lazy val `backend` = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ commonSettings ++ Seq(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq()
    )
  )
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala).aggregate(common, other)

lazy val `other` = (project in file("modules/other")).dependsOn(common)
lazy val `common` = project in file("modules/common")
```

Both `common` and `other` build.sbt look exactly the same. Essentially a standard Play Framework build.sbt file.

Project compiles okay, but the issue is IntelliJ is not recognizing files in `common` from `other`, even though in the parent, I declare the dependency order

Thanks!

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself? Any issue after reading the documentation ? Error details?

Comment: Added a comment so you can see @cchantep

Comment: And so? what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the reason, but sometimes having child `build.sbt` files doesn't work well. Try moving those settings to the root file.